# Explicitly computing the number of representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I went through some basic examples of finding irreducible complex representations of groups such as

1. $D_n$,
2. cyclic group of order $n$,
3. $A_4$,
4. $S_n$ for $n = 3, 4$.

We saw all the irreducible representations of $D_n$ and $C_n$ explicitly.  However for $A_4$, I just saw the $3$ one-dimensional representations explicitly. It hasn’t been mentioned about the other 3-dimensional representation at all.

So my question is, how exactly I compute all the irreducible representations explicitly. For example $A_4$ has one $3$-dimensional representation but I am not sure how to compute it. And when I am computing a representatation, how can I know if it is irreducible or not?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *computing* the irreducible representations? Only the degrees or also the values per conjugacy class? There are many ways to compute, one strategy is inducing known representations from a subgroup to the whole group. Irreducibility can be checked with the orthogonality relations.

Comment: In fact the three-dimensional irreducible representation of $A_4$ can be computed very easily as the so-called *deleted permutation module*: the natural $4$-dimensional permutation module is the direct sum of the trivial representation and the one you are looking for.

Comment: @NickyHekster, I am trying to say that using formulas, I can determine the number of irreducible representations(equal to conjugacy classes of the group G) and then I using some number theory methods(if I turn out to be lucky), I can find the number of irreducible representations and their degrees. For example $A_5$ has irreducible representation of degree $1,3,3,4,5$ and I know the degree $1$ representation.  But how do I compute the other representations explicitly. Similarly I am looking for ways to explicitly compute higher dimensional representations

Comment: @permutation_matrix You haven't really answered Nicky Hekster's question, which was what exactly do you mean you computing a representation explicitly.

Comment: By computing it explicitly I mean explicitly stating a homomorphism $\rho: G \to End_k(V)$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$.

Comment: Well I am still not sure what you mean by "stating a homomorphism". But in general computing representations of finite groups is  difficult (more difficult than computing character tables), so all that you can really do is to learn a bunch of techniques that work for small examples. I explained earlier how to do this for $A_4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Wait. How can I write down the character table without explicitly knowing the representation?  I am missing something.

Comment: The orthogonality relations give you a lot of information, which often enables you to compute the character tables for small groups. But there are general purpose algorithms to compute character tables, such as the Dixon-Scheider method.